# Is there a way to import an animated image created with Jquery to a Avi video?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, video-processing

I want to create a website where visitors can upload their images and after an automatic edit, images will have some effects like animation. After I want those animation effects to be added in specific timeframe in a avi video.

I know how to make those image effects with Jquery but I dont know if its possible to import them into an avi video file.

Is it possible? If not, is there any other way?